# gnome 3 fallback switch missing

Tags: gnome

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and installed Gnome-shell, but the Fallback switch in settings is missing. I see many tutorials where it should be located, but it's not there. Is there something i haven't installed that's causing this fallback switch not to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to logout first, then you can get to gnome-fallback by choosing the Gnome Classic session in the lightdm menu.